# How to bind both Clicked event and a Command, so the Command will be executed first?

Tags: c#, windows, mvvm, windows-runtime, windows-10-universal

My goal is to perform some business logic and then navigate to other page.
Also I would like to separate business logic from navigation as I believe that this process should not be delegated to ModelView logic according to the MVVM pattern. Please correct me if I'm wrong.
To achieve this I'm created a command in my ViewModel for business logic:

```
SubmitOrderCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(SubmitOrderExecute, SubmitOrderCanExecute);
...    
private void SubmitOrderExecute(string obj)
            {
                var rnd = new Random();
                int tableIndex = rnd.Next((int)base.Repository.Tables.Count());

                base.Repository.Orders.Add(
                    new Order()
                    {
                        Complete = false,
                        Expedite = true,
                        SpecialRequests = SpecialRequestText,
                        ...
                        Items = CurrentlySelectedMenuItems.ToList<MenuItem>()
                    });
                this.CurrentlySelectedMenuItems.Clear();
                //TODO:Have to navigate to other page  after doing all these stuff
            }
```

And here is the obvious XAML part, nothing special

```
<Button Content="Submit Order" Command="{Binding SubmitOrderCommand}" />
```

The question is, how to navigate to other Page, after my Command executed and follow MVVM pattern strictly. I know I could use EventTrigger, but looking for any other solutions if it exist...

Answer (score 2):

Add a service to navigate to the other page when you need it. 
It you use a service, it will not break the MVVM pattern.

If you have plusalsight account I recommend you this course: 
https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=practical-mvvm&author=gill-cleeren&name=practical-mvvm-m4&clip=0&mode=live

Comment: Thanks, its huge! Will buy Pluralsight account for this.